# How to remap keys on iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone

GOAL: Convert headset play button, and volume buttons to keys of my choosing.

With all of these new accessibility features like “switch control” and developer tools available is there any feasible way to map any kind of button press to a custom key?

Im willing to use a mouse, or even a small 9 key bluetooth keyboard. I just need to know if I can map a button to a key?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to alter the functions of standard controls.

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) please read point 2.5.9